# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. but the column does exist

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

I am trying to do something that i thought would be simple. Take the value from 1 datagridview and add it to a value in another datagridview.

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub DeleteBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DeleteBtn.Click
    Dim sl = SalesLinesTblDataGridView
    Dim st = StockTblDataGridView
    Dim sti As Integer = st.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim sli As Integer = sl.CurrentRow.Index

    If sl.RowCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox("No sales lines to delete!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    Else
        Dim DelM = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this sales line?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If DelM = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            StockTblBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("ID = '" & sl.Item(13, sli).Value & "'")

            st.Item(3, sti).Value = Val(st.Item(3, sti).Value) + Val(sl.Item(3, sli).Value)
            st.Item(5, sti).Value = Val(st.Item(5, sti).Value) + Val(sl.Item(3, sli).Value)
            SalesLinesTblBindingNavigator.DeleteItem.PerformClick()
            ResetBtn.PerformClick()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

it is erroring on

```
 st.Item(3, sti).Value = Val(st.Item(3, sti).Value) + Val(sl.Item(3, sli).Value)
```

with the exception in the title.

Can you please help.

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong column index in your `SalesLinesTblDataGridView` ? Try 13 instead of 3 : `st.Item(3, sti).Value = Val(st.Item(3, sti).Value) + Val(sl.Item(13, sli).Value)` ?

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it is actually column 3 that it needs to be. it works if i do it where the id matches the the id in the CurrentRow in the st datagrid but if the filter takes it to a different record i get this error. 

I have tried adding

    st.CurrentCell = st.Rows(0).Cells(1)

after the filter but this still didnt work. but i am confident it is to do with there being no currentrow in the st datagrid

Answer (score 0):

All working now. Never found out what was wrong but splitting the code to two buttons and using button2.perform click worked. Not sure what difference it made splitting the code after the filter and it is a little messier than i wanted but is working for now.